# i have error when i run npm , npm run watch , [webpack-cli] Error: Unknown option '--hide-modules'

Tags: laravel, npm, webpack, node-modules

ahmedrabee@ahmed-mac test-order % npm run watch

> watch
> NODE_ENV=development webpack --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js

[webpack-cli] Error: Unknown option '--hide-modules'
[webpack-cli] Run 'webpack --help' to see available commands and options

any help please

Comment: see if it helps `npm install laravel-mix@latest`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

That worked for me.

> softwareupdate --install-rosetta.

Credits:
https://github.com/mikaelbr/node-notifier/issues/361#issuecomment-968916810